# Google chart inside of popup box with some buttons in

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a project:

[fiddle project demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mithrand1r/M6YuK/1/)

Which suppose to create a `Google chart` which can be zoomed by clicking on it. Click is showing the to the user popup box with enlarged `div` containing same chart as before.

Problem I have encountered is that I cannot put anything more in the enlarged `div` - I wanted to put there a button which would close the box ( right now clicking anywhere inside `div` is calling  `setVisible('layer1')` function - which is unfortunate because I cannot use `getSelection` function on the google chart)

I believe the problem is this fragment which contain section for zoomed chart:

```
<div id ="la" class ="layer2" style="width: 900px; height: 700px; background-color: #f3f3f3;"><button type="button">Close Me!</button> 
    <div id="layer1" class ="layer1" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: #f3f3f3;"> <a href="javascript:setVisible('layer1')"><strong>Hide</strong></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main problem is that `<button type="button">Click Me!</button>` is not shown at all...

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course your button isn't visible: you have `layer2`'s css set to `visibility: hidden;`